# Why we use activation function after convolution layer in Convolution Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, activation

I'm new to machine learning and one of the things that I don't understand about Convolution neural networks, is that why we perform activation after convolution layer.

Comment: This question is better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/, since it is not about programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a convolution followed by a convolution is a convolution.  Therefore, a convolutional neural network of arbitrary depth without intervening non-convolutional layers of some sort (such as a relu layer) is fundamentally equivalent to a convolutional neural network with only one layer.  This is because composing linear transformations is linear:

```
y = m1*(m2*x + b2) + b1
  = m1 * m2 * x + m1 * b2 + b1
```

Which is just a linear function...  Why learn two when you can learn just one and it is exactly the same?  This logic applies even to locally linear functions (convolutions are locally linear).  Thus, for either convolutional NNs (but also vanilla NNs) we must do something, anything, non-linear in-between the linear layers.  One incredibly simple non-linear function is the [relu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) which is a basic "bend".

Answer (score 0):

CNN is one of the neural network. The basic idea behind neural network is that when you have enough inputs then the neuron is triggered based on the computing of activation function. 
The basic neural network known as Multi later perceptron (MLP) in which you have have X - dimensional input that you pass to 1st MLP layer and the process goes on to the further layer and eventually there is one neuron at the end where in the output is computed which might be classification or regression based on the problem.

In the similar way after you apply filter/kernel on the input image. After that you need to apply element wise activation function like relu or sigmoid on that convolved image. Activation function produces an output if you have enough inputs which gets as input to other layers.

Answer (score 0):

I know your concern and reasoning is this: Kernels(like for blurring etc) extract/identify certain features they are designed for in normal image processing tasks and so, why the need for them in CNN since there use in CNN is to extract/identify features as well?

The answer is simply this: in CNN, you don't know the kernel to use before hand, it is created on-the-fly based on the errors back propagation. Now, the kernels can be in the position of having to extract complex features. What do you think now? Do you think simple multiplication and addition as in the convolutional process is enough to extract complex features? Atleast you need complex functions and hence, the need for non-linearity of activation functions after convolution. Have a nice day